# FullCalendar, dayclick function

Tags: javascript, php, fullcalendar

I am trying to do a calendar using the FullCalendar plugin. Here is my code,

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta charset='utf-8' />
    <link href='fullcalendar.css' rel='stylesheet' />
    <link href='fullcalendar.print.css' rel='stylesheet' media='print' />
    <script src='moment.min.js'></script>
    <script src='jquery.min.js'></script>
    <script src='fullcalendar.min.js'></script>
    <script>

        $(document).ready(function() {

            $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
                header: {
                    left: 'prev,next today',
                    center: 'title',
                    right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
                },

                selectable: true,
                selectHelper: true,
                select: function(start, end, jsEvent, view){
                  window.location = "testing.php";
                },



            });

        });

    </script>
    <style>

        body {
            margin: 40px 10px;
            padding: 0;
            font-family: "Lucida Grande",Helvetica,Arial,Verdana,sans-serif;
            font-size: 14px;
        }

        #calendar {
            max-width: 900px;
            margin: 0 auto;
        }

    </style>
    </head>
    <body>

        <div id='calendar'></div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

When I click on a date, the calendar redirects me to the test.php (which is what I want). How do I code it in a way that, for example, when the user presses on January 10th, the details (which is in the database) will be echoed out to that php. (testing.php).

Any suggestion on how my testing.php file should be done?

To add on, it is somehow a feature which is similar to this `http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_database.asp`

Comment: Can you put together a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)?

Comment: Hi sir, sorry but due to my inability, i don't know how my fiddle not working. However here's an image of it http://postimg.org/image/5gexkfeez/ sorry for inconvenience

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fullcalendar. linking to database](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34618960/fullcalendar-linking-to-database)